# iPhone - Font used for Toolbar buttons

Tags: iphone, fonts, uibarbuttonitem

Could you tell me which font is used to display text on Toolbar buttons ?
I'm searching this to make a custom button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helvetica-Bold, 12 pt

Although you may be better off just creating the graphic (background) for the button and using the default title property of the button to set the relevant text.

Comment: But doing like this, I may lose the inner shadow of the text

Comment: @Oliver Updated original answer to take the shadow (text) into account.